# Lack of Key Validation and Autocomplete with React-i18next's t Function

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I'm experiencing an issue with the `t` function in react-i18next, as it doesn't provide autocomplete or validation for translation keys. Here's my setup:

**My i18n configuration:**

```
import generalEN from "@/i18n/en/general.json";
import myPageEN from "@/i18n/en/my-page.json";
import i18next from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
    debug: true,
    defaultNS: "general",
    lng: "en",
    resources: {
        en: {
            myPage: myPageEN,
            general: generalEN,
        },
    },
});
```

**Resources configuration in resources.ts:**

```
import myPageEN from "../i18n/en/myPage.json";
import generalEN from "../i18n/en/general.json";

const resources = {
    myPage: myPageEN,
    general: generalEN,
} as const;

export default resources;
```

**How I use the t function:**

```
import i18n from '@/i18n/config';

i18n.t('myPage.title');
```

Unlike the `<Trans>` component, the `t` function does not provide key validation or autocomplete. This behavior has the `t` function **outside and inside** a component. I'm looking for a way to make the `t` function behave like the `<Trans>` component in this regard. Is there something I'm missing in my setup, or is this the expected behavior of the `t` function in react-i18next? Any advice or help would be great. Thank you!

My setup was from the step by step guide from the offical [documentation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks)